# Add Autoplay jquery slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code following where I am unable to add Autoplay on the slider. Can anyone help me with this?

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $(".slider").jCarouselLite({
                    btnNext: ".next",
                    btnPrev: ".prev",
                    visible: 5
                });
            });

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('img.captify').captify({                  
                    speedOver: 'fast',
                    speedOut: 'normal',                     
                    hideDelay: 500,                     
                    animation: 'slide',                     
                    prefix: '',                     
                    opacity: '0.7',                     
                    className: 'caption-bottom',                        
                    position: 'bottom',                     
                    spanWidth: '100%'
                });
            });

        </script>
```

How can I Add Autoplay on this slider

Comment: please add a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I am unable to add demo there. This is the site from where I downloaded the the code. But the slide doesn't play automatically.

 

http://www.onextrapixel.com/examples/jquery-jcarousel-lite-and-jquery-captify/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() { 
  $(".slider").jCarouselLite({
    auto:500,
    speed:800,
    btnNext: ".next",                     
    btnPrev: ".prev",                     
    visible: 5                 
  });             
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".slider .jCarouselLite").jCarouselLite({
    auto: 800,
    speed: 1000
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and it is working in a different way... But with your Help

Comment: It worked in this way that, I added "auto: 800,
    speed: 1000
});"  on 
$(".slider").jCarouselLite function and it worked. Thanks very very much